# Why is $(f(x))'$ shortened $f'(x)$

Tags: notation

Why is $(f(x))'$ shortened $f'(x)$?

This makes the chain rule look awkward, as $(f(g(x)))'\neq f'(g(x))$, but rather $f'(g(x))\!\times\! g(x)$, and makes it difficult to remember.

It's also an awkward way as $(f(x))' = ('\circ f)(x)$, and changing the order of the functions makes no sense, as $'$ should come first.

Comment: (1) You do not have a balanced set of parentheses in your first equation. (2) How would you denote the derivative of the function at $x=2$? Writing $(f(2))'$ is very bad. Differentiation and evaluation do not commute.

Comment: From one technical point of view you're quite right that the notation $(f(x))'$ should not be used.  When that point of view is followed, the chain rule may be written as $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This certainly isn't the only example of poorly thought out basic calculus notation that nevertheless continues to be taught in introductory courses. We really ought to fix this one of these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculus seems to be a wonderful source of bad notation; I've never seen the notation $(f(x))'$ used that much. $f'(x)$ captures things better, since the $'$ mark applies to the function, not to the expression as a whole, and is what I usually see - so I would say the $(f(x))'$ is more of a corruption of $f'(x)$ than the other way round. I'd generally state the chain rule as:
$$(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
which looks a lot clearer.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that $'$ only works on functions, so $f'(x)$ is actually $(f)'(x)$. I always thought $'$ was some sort of function composition  with $f$, but it's a function with $f$ as the argument? So $(f(g(x)))'$ is just as nonsense as $(f(x))'$?

Comment: @fvel Yeah, exactly; $'$ maps differentiable functions to functions. (Notice that, were it a composition, then if $f(x)=g(x)$ then $f(x)'=g(x)'$, which is of course, not true).

Comment: $x^2 = x \iff (x^2)' = (x)' \iff 2x = 1 \iff x = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Why was I not aware of this. Not related to my question, but what's the general notation for such a function? $g(f)(x)$?

Comment: @fvel Certainly $g(f)(x)$ is acceptable, though it's pretty uncommon - more common is just talking about $g(f)$ as a function, rather than evaluating it anywhere as $g(f)(x)$, or to see expressions like $T_f(x)$ to represent some transformation $T$ of $f$ applied to $x$ - or you'll see expressions like $f'$ or $\int f$ or $\hat{f}$ which all are functions of $f$. It's a stylistic issue where, regrettably, the very natural notation of $g(f)(x)$ gets used less than weird other notations.